# Good way to extrapolate time series data based on min/max/mean and sample size

Tags: statistics

I have a small set of annual data on the operations cost of solar power plants that I'd like to extrapolate into future years for some basic modelling. For each year 2011 through 2018, I have:

- The mean operating cost of each plant in dollars per kilowatt of capacity
- The min and max operating costs in the sample
- Number of plants included in the sample (with additional plants added to the sample each year)
- Total combined capacity (in kilowatts) of all plants in the sample

The data looks something like this:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{Mean} & \text{Min} & \text{Max}& \text{Count}& \text{Capacity} \\ \hline
\text{2011} & $65 & $53 & $71 & 9 & 199 \\ \hline
\text{2012} & $34 & $22 & $44 & 19 & 326 \\ \hline
\text{2013} & $47 & $34 & $54 & 29 & 463 \\ \hline
\text{2014} & $26 & $18 & $44 & 31 & 476 \\ \hline
\text{2015} & $23 & $16 & $54 & 50 & 673 \\ \hline
\text{2016} & $24 & $19 & $42 & 56 & 848 \\ \hline
\text{2017} & $27 & $20 & $39 & 60 & 995 \\ \hline
\text{2018} & $30 & $19 & $68 & 76 & 1,227 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

What would be a reasonable way to estimate the mean operating costs for years in 2019 and forward?

Comment: A couple of clarifications: (1) Is the min and max operating cost in sample for each plant for each year or for the overall period for all plants? (2) Total combined capacity of all plants in sample -- is this also available for each year or is it aggregate for whole period?

If you don't mind, could you post the data tables. Even dummy data would help with understanding your data schema.

Comment: Sure, I added a table to the question with some dummy data, hopefully that helps! To answer those questions, 1. the min and max are the costs from the least expensive and most expensive plants in the sample that year, and 2. the total combined capacity is aggregated for the whole period, and I don't have individual plants' capacities.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of caveats.

1. We are assuming that the plant technologies are similar and older years and newer years are comparable
2. There may be specific operating costs that are higher for older plants than newer plants (eg: repairs and maintenance). Since the sample data does not provide any way for identifying this reliably, we are ignoring it.

A simple method might be assigning weightage for the time periods.

Let us say the weight $W_t$ we want to assign for time period $t$ is

- inversely proportional to how recent the data point is (ie., older years get lesser weightage). The rationale for this is we are biasing the costs with the recency effect considered. Any operational optimizations or cost increases carried out through the most recent years are given higher weightage.
- inversely proportional to the $\sqrt n_t$ where $n_t$ is the count of plants in the sample for that time period. The rationale is that margin of error in a sample is inversely proportional to the square root of the size of the sample (in a normal distribution).
- inversely proportional to the $\sqrt C_t$ where $C_t$ is the total capacity for that period. Rationale is same as above.

So, we have

$$W_t \propto {t \over \sqrt {n_t \times C_t}}$$

$$W_t = {k \times t \over {\sqrt {n_t \times C_t}}}$$ where $k$ is a constant.

The relative weightage (a real value between 0 and 1) is then given by

$$w_t = {W_t \over \sum_j W_j}, j > 0$$

Note that the proportionality constant $k$ is cancelled when we take the relative weightage.

$j$ in the denominator is the index of the time period and we take $j > 0$ to avoid multiplying by 0 causing the term to vanish.

Then we can then predict the average operating cost per KW for future years using a weighted average of costs of prior years with weights calculated as given above.

This will keep your model simple and explainable and not reliant on any hypothesis that is difficult to prove.

I would also suggest using quarterly data, if available. You will get higher accuracy of prediction with 4x data points and also factor any seasonal impacts of costs without complicating the model too much.